# JavaScript convert string to operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert a string representation of an operator to the operator itself in comparisons.

---

For example, something like

```
{obj1} '==' {obj2}
```

should be:

```
{obj1} == {obj2}
```

OR

```
{obj1} '!==' {obj2}
```

should be:

```
{obj1} !== {obj2}
```

---

I can use `eval()`, but that forces the objects to be compared to be converted to a string, causing `===` (strict type check) comparisons useless.

For example, in the following example, `eval` would give wrong results:

```js
const obj = "5"
const obj2 = 5

const operator = '===';

eval(`console.log(${obj} ${operator} ${obj2})`) //outputs true, incorrect (obj is of type string, obj2 is of type number)

console.log(obj === obj2) //outputs false, correct
```

How should I approach this?

---

**Possible approach**

One way that I came up with is just to go through the `if else` ladder and let js handle the comparison instead of parsing the comparison operator.

Something like

```js
if(condition === '!=='){
  return before_OrderRequest.Id !== after_OrderRequest.Id
}else if (condition === '==='){
  return before_OrderRequest.Id === after_OrderRequest.Id
}
//...more if statements
```

Comment: I described exactly why `eval()` is falling short of our requirement, or maybe there is a way to just eval the condition operator that I don't know of, please explain.

Comment: @Spectric There is literally a sample string in the second line.

Comment: Currently the string contains the placeholders and the operator, we are programatically replacing the placeholders with the actual values, after which we are then running the string through an `eval()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with the similar issue, Please understand that my question is built on sort of a false premise. Allow me to explain...

If you look at my sample executable snippet, you'll notice that I'm using the eval like below

```
eval(`console.log(${obj} ${operator} ${obj2})`)
```

But this usage by me is wrong, here I'm using string interpolation which is forcing the value for `obj2` into a string.

The correct usage should have been as below...

```js
const obj = "5"
const obj2 = 5

const operator1 = '===';
const operator2 = '!==';

eval(`console.log(obj ${operator1} obj2)`) //outputs false which is correct
eval(`console.log(obj ${operator2} obj2)`) //outputs true which is correct

console.log(obj === obj2) //outputs false which is correct
```

Have added this as an answer, instead of just editing the question, so that there is context for someone who is facing similar type of challenge.

Answer (score 4):

You can define an object with the string representation of operators as properties that return an arrow function performing the corresponding comparison.

```js
const compare = {
  '==': (a, b) => a == b,
  '!=': (a, b) => a != b,
  '===' : (a, b) => a === b,
  '!==' : (a, b) => a !== b
}

const obj1 = 1;
const obj2 = 2;

console.log(compare['=='](obj1, obj2))
console.log(compare['!='](obj1, obj2))
console.log(compare['==='](obj1, obj2))
console.log(compare['!=='](obj1, obj2))
```

Comment: This looks like something similar to what I came up with, but a bit more elegant, so I'm gonna go ahead with this unless there is some better alternative. Thanks.